# Datatable returning 0. There is no row at position 2 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to remove a row or rows from gridview using checkbox; however when I check the box it gives this error message: **There is no row at position 2**. In adding this line to debug dt.rows.count > 0, I recognized that count is 0. The data shown in the gridview is pulled from a database table.

```
  for(int i = GridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = GridView2.Rows[i];
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("chkInvoice") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
    {
       dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
  GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: How are you initializing `dt `?

Comment: dt = new DataTable(); in page load

Comment: So new data table won't have any rows by default. That's why you are seeing Rows.Count zero

Comment: I believe what @ChetanRanpariya was trying to ask is how and where are you populating "dt"? Can you please post your Page_Load event function?

Comment: i remove that line but it only show a count of 1 when they are 3 rows

Comment: when i do the search is dataset i'm using to populate the gridview

Comment: Did you get your problem solved @Jane?

Comment: no I did not solve it as yet

Answer (score 0):

For your code above to work, 'dt' will have to have a copy of the same rows, in the same order as GridView2.  However, instead of removing rows from a separate table, you could just remove them from the gridView's buffer. Using 
`GridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);`

Your loop is running backwards so there should be no issue with removing lines as there would be if you were running from first to last.  Now if you need to track the rows being removed so that you can issue a database delete, that is another issue.

Update: RemoveAt is a method on Rows which is a dataGridViewRowCollection.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx